# Repeat Rxjava chain

Tags: java, rx-java

I am getting data then I am doing an async request to check flag and if it is false, I want to repeat this step for 5 times with 1 sec delay until it gets true and continue processing or throw exception.

```
return getData()
           .flatMap(data -> checkFlag()
                    .map(b -> {
                        if (b) {
                            return data;
                        } else {
                            throw new Exception();
                        }
                    }))
           .retryWhen((Flowable<Throwable> f) -> f.take(5).delay(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
           .flatmapCompletable(data -> sendEvent(data))

Maybe<Dto> getData();
Maybe<Boolean> checkFlag();
Completable sendEvent(Dto dto);
```

I am using retryWhen(), but because of it I have to throw Exception on false case. Maybe there is a better way to do it and to avoid working from exception?
If it is not, then how can I retry only for specific Exception?

```
.retryWhen(e -> e.flatMap(error -> {
                if (error instanceof CustomException) {
                    return Flowable.just(null);//doesn't trigger repeat
                }
                return Flowable.error(error);
            }).take(5).delay(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
```

Comment: Hint: even when doing pseudo code, be diligent about naming. never ever call a variable "boolean".

Comment: Please fix the code indention to improve the readability.

Answer (score 0):

Below could be an alternative (pardon me for the heavy indentation):

```
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Observable;
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Single;
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.schedulers.Schedulers;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Answer {

    private static final int MAX_ATTEMPT = 5;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Single<String> solution =
                Single.just("dummy data")
                        .flatMap(data ->
                                Observable.range(1, MAX_ATTEMPT)
                                        .map(Answer::checkFlag)
                                        .delay(result -> {
                                            if (!result) {
                                                return Observable
                                                        .just(false)
                                                        .delay(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS, Schedulers.trampoline());
                                            }
                                            return Observable.just(true);
                                        })
                                        .takeUntil(result -> result == true)
                                        .toList()
                                        .map(results -> results.size() < MAX_ATTEMPT || (results.size() == MAX_ATTEMPT && results.get(MAX_ATTEMPT - 1)))
                                        .map(result -> {
                                            if (!result) {
                                                throw new Exception("check flag error");
                                            }
                                            return data;
                                        })
                        );

        solution.subscribe(
                (data) -> {
                    System.out.println("onSuccess: " + data);
                },
                (error) -> {
                    System.out.println("onError: " + error);
                }
        );
    }

    private static boolean checkFlag(int attempt) {
        System.out.println("check flag attempt #" + attempt);
        return attempt == MAX_ATTEMPT;
    }

}
```